# SEO for pages that load from a database?

Tags: seo, database, dynamic

I developed a website that has only one page in the public html directory (index.php). All content is dynamically loaded as different pages.

I believe that what we type into this site is stored in a database, and that the search engine finds these pages like any static pages...

How can I SEO my pages for Google?

Comment: You *do* have multiple pages, just not multiple files. Marco's answer tells you a) that you can dynamically optimize, and b) you should use "clean URLs".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you want to SEO page contents** you need 1st to apply [Google Webmaster guidelines](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769) (at least the [basic guide](http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf)) to your dynamic generated pages, therefor you need your dynamic page to set properly in page at least the `<title>` and `<h1>`, `<meta description>` by retrieving this contents from the DB. It should be different for each page, Google seems to dislike repeated contents and final users dislike them too.

**Then if you want to SEO page URLs**, you basically needs to make URLs more human readable, as for a very general example: if a page talks about 'cats' the url should be something like: `http://...index.php?id=cats` (or maybe better `http://.../cats`) just avoid `http://...index.php?id=54637`
In order to accomplish this task [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5471/seo-adding-an-unecessary-description-key-in-dynamic-url-is-it-good-or-not) they suggested me to create in DB table an `alias` field for each item/article, so supposing your DB primary key is an integer just cerate a another field called 'alias' (this field muts be UNIQUE **no duplicates**, as for the primary key) and use it in your URLs.

Comment: thank you Marco Demaio for your reply...but as i have known that the meta tags and title tags play key role in SEO. If i dynamically generate content for  these tags, will search engine determine the content

Comment: @explorex: sorry at this point I don't understand what you mean. It does not matter fro SE how your content are generated, SE are NOT going to read into your DB/server app code to evaluate if it's well designed. So they don't mind how the content are generated as long as these contents are written in pages.

Answer (score 4):

Search engines have no idea your content comes from a database. All they see is the HTML your server side code generates. So, there are no special rules, tips, or techniques for database generated content. The same rules as any other content, dynamic or not, apply (see Marco's answer).

(Before someone says you need search engine friendly URLs I should point out that isn't specific to database content which is what this question is asking. SE friendly URLs apply to any kind of dynamic content and static content as well).