# SEO purpose: Does Google prefer html sites than wordpress sites?

Tags: seo, html, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SEO for pages that load from database](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5704/seo-for-pages-that-load-from-database)

Will html sites have any advantages over blog sites while getting analyzed by Google bot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It doesn't matter whether you have a site in plain HTML or in wordpress. What matters the most to Google bot is the uniqueness of your content and the quantity of text that you provide. **Content is Everything**

Answer (score 0):

If your Wordpress site uses query strings in the URLs then it may be less easy for Google to index. Just make sure you enable clean URLs when setting it up.

Comment: This is incorrect, it will be just as easy to crawl but it may not index as well.

Comment: I have updated the answer.